# Я написал код с правильным ответом, но я хотел бы добавить ещё один правильный ответ. Как это можно реализовать?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я написал код в котором правильным ответом является число 1 но я хотел бы добавить ещё один правильный ответ например число 2. Как это можно реализовать?

```
n = input("Vvedite chislo ot 1 do 9: ")
while n != str("1"):
    n = input("Vvedite chislo ot 1 do 9: ")
else:
    print("grun")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = '0'
while n not in ["1", "2"]:
    n = input("Vvedite chislo ot 1 do 9: ")
else:
    print("grun")
```

Или так

```
while True:
    n = input("Vvedite chislo ot 1 do 9: ")
    if n in ["1", "2"]:
        print("grun")
        break
```